# Finding $\int_{0}^{e^2}(\frac{1}{\log{x}}-(\frac{1}{\log x})^2).\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

Finding $$\int_{0}^{e^2}(\frac{1}{\log{x}}-(\frac{1}{\log x})^2).\mathrm{d}x$$

I came upon this problem online, and the answer is given to be $(\frac{e^2}{2}) - e$. However, Wolfram Alpha states that the integral does not converge.

[image: Q]

Comment: Well, Wolfram is quite right, have you studied improper integrals ?

Comment: The integrand blows up badly near $x=1$.

Comment: @Victor Not yet. Could any tweak in the question give the given answer? (Considering there to be a typo)

Comment: @Gaussian_Ramanujan, it is just wron g typo , you can check wolfram alpha and calculate the below integral you will got :(e²/2)-e almost 0.97

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look the integral that you meant is  :$$\int_{e}^{e^2}(\frac{1}{\log{x}}-(\frac{1}{\log x})^2).\mathrm{d}x$$

Hint : your integral doesn't converge ,you have a singularity at x=1 and

should be begin from 2 to e² as the definition of logarithm integral function.

you can check this for the [offset of logarithmic function](https://www.google.dz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQygQwAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLogarithmic_integral_function%23Offset_logarithmic_integral&ei=ro2QVayCKsvjUY_EgeAK&usg=AFQjCNGodZKCKCsDBZ5RBtdAgVkDfpdjzw&sig2=pRi13_R77SEG4wmZ01X4FA)

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting $$\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{\log ^2(x)}=\frac{\log(x)-1}{\log ^2(x)}$$ we recognize something like $\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$. So $v=\log(x)$ and then $u'=1$ so $u=x$.

Then the antiderivative is simply $$\int\Big(\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{\log ^2(x)}\Big)\,dx=\frac{x}{\log (x)}$$ So $$\int_a^{e^2}\Big(\frac{1}{\log (x)}-\frac{1}{\log ^2(x)}\Big)\,dx=\frac{e^2}{2}-\frac{a}{\log(a)}$$ To get the answer from the book, the only solution is $a=e$.

One more typo in a textbook.